# %%I in windows batch doesn't manage name with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file

In windows 10, I need to make a batch with a loop on the subfolder names in a folder, I did the following, but the problem is the %%I doesn't manage the folder name with spaces, it takes only the first part:

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%I IN ('dir /b C:\Users\Thomas\Music') DO (
    ECHO %%I)
```

If the folder "Music" contains the folder "My music", then echo %%I will print only "My".

Comment: `FOR /F "delims=" %%I  IN ('dir /b /AD C:\Users\Thomas\Music') DO (` Read http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! How to you handle the %%I after that? I tried to put it in a variable with "set my_var=%%I" but that doesn't work...

Comment: It works with the delayed expansion as said by Magoo in next comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best-practice concept shown in a *commented* `.bat` script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('dir /b /AD "%UserProfile%\Music" 2^>NUL') DO (
        rem process a FOR-loop variable directly
    ECHO For_variable "%%~I"
        rem set a FOR-loop variable as an environment variable value
    set "_myVar=%%~I"      see tilde which would strip double quotes
        rem process an environment variable INside a FOR-loop body
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
      echo Env_variable "!_myVar!"
    ENDLOCAL
        rem process an environment variable OUTside a FOR-loop body
    call :ProcessMyVar
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:ProcessMyVar
      rem process an environment variable OUTside a FOR-loop body
  echo Env_var_Call "%_myVar%"
goto :eof
```

**Output** shows that even names with `cmd`-poisonous characters like percent or exclamation (etc. etc.) are processed properly:

```
==> tree "%UserProfile%\Music"
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 0000005F F2DF:F89D
C:\USERS\USER\MUSIC
├───100% My Tunes!
└───My Songs!

==> D:\bat\SO\39697872.bat
For_variable "100% My Tunes!"
Env_variable "100% My Tunes!"
Env_var_Call "100% My Tunes!"
For_variable "My Songs!"
Env_variable "My Songs!"
Env_var_Call "My Songs!"

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%I`, `%~I` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`>`, `&` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`%%` doubled percent sign, `^` caret, double quotes)  [Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: Many thanks, it seems perfect for what I need, I go try that

Answer (score 2):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('dir /b /ad C:\Users\Thomas\Music') DO (
```

... and use `"%%I"` where you want to use the name-containing-spaces (ie. quote the constructed string) - a principle that applies wherever batch uses strings containing separators like <kbd>Space</kbd>

The `/ad` selects directorynames instead of filenames.

Adding a further switch, `/s` will scan the entire subdirectory-tree.

Assignment of string values to variables is best done with

```
set "var=%variablefrom%"
```

or in the case of a *metavariable* (eg the loop-control variable `%%I` in your code) you need

```
set "var=%%I"
```

BUT you should investigate the topic of `delayed expansion` (many items here) if you want to use the value of the variable assigned (`var`) within the loop.